# How to select last element with specific class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a list of elements and five elements will always have the class name of "current". the rest of the element will not. For example:

```
<li class="item current"></li>
<li class="item current"></li>
<li class="item current"></li>
<li class="item current"></li>
<li class="item current"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
```

How can I select the fifth li element with the class name "current"? In other words, I want to apply a certain style to the last element with a class name of "current". The class names will also change depending on a button click. If the user clicks the next button, the first element will no longer have the "current" class and the sixth element will have the "current" class added. What the HTML above needs to look like is:

```
<li class="item current"></li>
<li class="item current"></li>
<li class="item current"></li>
<li class="item current"></li>
<li class="item current" style="margin-right: 0;"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
```

After the user clicks the next button, the html would look like:

```
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item current"></li>
<li class="item current"></li>
<li class="item current"></li>
<li class="item current"></li>
<li class="item current" style="margin-right: 0;"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)

```
$('.item.current:last')
```

or [last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/)

```
$('.item.current').last()
```

Answer (score 3):

With [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector:

```
$('li.current:last').css('color', '#f00');
```

Or alternatively with [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
$('li.current').slice(-1).css('color', '#f00');
```

Comment: This doesn't add the css to last element after the button click. When I click the next button, the css stays on the fourth "current" element.